# How to login with session in laravel by using bigquery dataset

Tags: php, laravel, google-bigquery

Here , I am trying to login with session by using raw bigquery in laravel then show the error like this

{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [1:65]", "errors": [ { "message": "Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [1:65]", "domain": "global", "reason": "invalidQuery", "location": "q", "locationType": "parameter" } ], "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }

I am using this code in laravel controller

$input = $this->request->all();
$credentials = $request->only('submision_id','vol_password');

```
        $submision_id = $credentials['submision_id'];
        $vol_password = $credentials['vol_password'];
        
        $bigQuery = $this->bigQueryContext->context();
        $dataset = $this->bigQueryContext->getDataset($bigQuery);
        $table = $dataset->table('bbds23.volunteer_password');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `bbds23.volunteer_password` WHERE submision_id = $submision_id AND vol_password = $vol_password";

        $jobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query);
        $submission = $bigQuery->runQuery($jobConfig);



    // $credentials = $request->only('submision_id', 'vol_password');
    // $submission = Volunteer::where('submision_id', $credentials['submision_id'])->first();

   if ($submission && Hash::check($credentials['vol_password'], $submission->vol_password)) {

    $request->session()->put('submision_id', $submission->submision_id);
    $request->session()->put('vol_password', $submission->vol_password);
```

but show the error

Comment: Please be warned that your query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked